# How do I translate mouse movement distances to SVG coordinate space?

Tags: javascript, svg, matrix

I have an SVG visualization of the distribution of CSS4 color keywords in HSL space here: https://meyerweb.com/eric/css/colors/hsl-dist.html

I recently added zooming via the mouse wheel, and panning via mouse clack-and-drag.  I’m able to convert a point from screen space to SVG coordinate space using `matrixTransform`, `.getScreenCTM()`, and `.inverse()` thanks to example code I found online, but how do I convert mouse movements during dragging? Right now I’m just shifting the `viewBox` coordinates by the X and Y values from `event`, which means the image drag is faster than the mouse movement when zoomed in.

As an example, suppose I’m zoomed in on the image and am dragging to pan, and I jerk the mouse leftwards and slightly downwards.  `event.movementX` returns `-37` and `event.movementY` returns `6`.  How do I determine how far that equates to in SVG coordinates, so that the `viewBox` coordinates are shifted properly?

*(**Note:** I’m aware that there are libraries for this sort of thing, but I’m intentionally writing vanilla JS code in order to learn more about both SVG and JS.  So please, don’t post “lol just use library X” and leave it at that.  Thanks!)*

**Edited to add:** I was asked to post code.  Posting the entire JS seems overlong, but this is the function that fires on `mousemove` events:

```
function dragger(event) {
    var target = document.getElementById('color-wheel');
    var coords = parseViewBox(target);
    coords.x -= event.movementX;
    coords.y -= event.movementY;
    changeViewBox(target,coords);
}
```

If more is needed, then view source on the linked page; all the JS is at the top of the page.  Nothing is external except for a file that just contains all the HSL values and color names for the visualization.

Comment: Hi Eric. Is this an amount of code that you could add directly to your post?

Comment: I’m not sure how much of it would be relevant, but I’ll add the function I think needs to be modified.

Answer (score 10):

My recommendation:
Don't worry about the `movementX`/`Y` properties on the event.
Just worry about where the mouse started and where it is now.

(This has the additional benefit that you get the same result even if you miss some events: maybe because the mouse moved out of the window, or maybe because you want to group events so you only run the code once per animation frame.)

For where the mouse started, you measure that on the mousedown event.
Convert it to a position in the SVG coordinates, using the method you were using,
with `.getScreenCTM().inverse()` and `.matrixTransform()`.
After this conversion, you don't care where on the *screen* this point is. You only care about where it is in the picture.  That's the point in the picture that you're always going to move to be underneath the mouse.

On the mousemove events, you use that same conversion method to find out where the mouse currently is within the current SVG coordinate system.  Then you figure out how far that is from the point (again, in SVG coordinates) that you want underneath the mouse.  That's the amount that you use to transform the graphic.  I've followed your example and am doing the transform by shifting the `x` and `y` parts of the `viewBox`:

```
function move(e) {
  var targetPoint = svgCoords(event, svg);
  shiftViewBox(anchorPoint.x - targetPoint.x,
               anchorPoint.y - targetPoint.y);
}
```

You can also shift the graphic around with a `transform` on a group (`<g>` element) within the SVG; just be sure to use that same group element for the `getScreenCTM()` call that converts from the `clientX`/`Y` event coordinates.

Full demo for the drag to pan. I've skipped all your drawing code and the zooming effect.
But the zoom should still work, because the only position you're saving in global values is already converted into SVG coordinates.

```js
var svg = document.querySelector("svg");
var anchorPoint;

function shiftViewBox(deltaX, deltaY) {
 svg.viewBox.baseVal.x += deltaX;
 svg.viewBox.baseVal.y += deltaY;
}

function svgCoords(event,elem) {
 var ctm = elem.getScreenCTM();
 var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
    // Note: rest of method could work with another element,
    // if you don't want to listen to drags on the entire svg.
    // But createSVGPoint only exists on <svg> elements.
 pt.x = event.clientX;
 pt.y = event.clientY;
 return pt.matrixTransform(ctm.inverse());
}

svg.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  anchorPoint = svgCoords(event, svg);
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", move);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", cancelMove);
});

function cancelMove(e) {
  window.removeEventListener("mousemove", move);
  window.removeEventListener("mouseup", cancelMove);
  anchorPoint = undefined;
}

function move(e) {
  var targetPoint = svgCoords(event, svg);
  shiftViewBox(anchorPoint.x - targetPoint.x,
               anchorPoint.y - targetPoint.y);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

svg {
  margin: auto;
  width: 70vmin;
  height: 70vmin;
  border: thin solid gray;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-40 -40 80 80">
  <polygon fill="skyBlue"
           points="0 -40, 40 0, 0 40 -40 0" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

So the script needs something so that the vectors moved by the SVG are coordinated against the vectors moved by the mouse on screen. Despite the event being on your target, your SVG, the MouseEvent properties relate to your screen alone.

> The movementX read-only property of the MouseEvent interface provides the difference in the X coordinate of the mouse pointer between the given event and the previous mousemove event. In other words, the value of the property is computed like this: currentEvent.movementX = currentEvent.screenX - previousEvent.screenX.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/movementX

> The screenX read-only property of the MouseEvent interface provides the horizontal coordinate (offset) of the mouse pointer in global (screen) coordinates.

So what you're measuring, and to the best of my knowledge the only thing you *can* measure direcly without additional libraries or complication, is the movement of the pointer in pixel terms across the screen. The only way to make this work in terms of vector for movement of your SVG is to translate the on screen movement to the dimensions that are relevant to your scaled SVG.

My initial thinking was that you would be able to work out the scaling of the SVG object, using some combination of its viewbox and its actual width on the screen. **Naturally what would initially appear sensible is not.** This approach won't work, if it appears to it would be purely by chance.

But it turns out that the solution is essentially to use the same type of code you've used in your scaling when you approach your mouse movements. The `.getScreenCTM()` and `.inverse()` functions are exactly what you'll need again. But instead of trying to find a single point on the SVG to work from, you need to find out what the on-screen distance translates to in the SVG by comparing two points on the SVG instead.

What I provide here isn't necessarily the most optimal solution but hopefully helps explain and gives you something to work further from...

```
function dragger(event) {
    var target = document.getElementById('color-wheel');
    var coords = parseViewBox(target);


    //Get an initial point in the SVG to start measuring from
    var start_pt = target.createSVGPoint();

    start_pt.x = 0;
    start_pt.y = 0;

    var svgcoord = start_pt.matrixTransform(target.getScreenCTM().inverse());


    //Create a point within the same SVG that is equivalent to 
    //the px movement by the pointer
    var comparison_pt = target.createSVGPoint();

    comparison_pt.x = event.movementX;
    comparison_pt.y = event.movementY;

    var svgcoord_plus_movement = comparison_pt.matrixTransform(target.getScreenCTM().inverse());


    //Use the two SVG points created from screen position values to determine 
    //the in-SVG distance to change coordinates
    coords.x -=  (svgcoord_plus_movement.x - svgcoord.x);


    //Repeat the above, but for the Y axis
    coords.y -= (svgcoord_plus_movement.y - svgcoord.y);


    //Deliver the changes to the SVG to update the view
    changeViewBox(target,coords);
}
```

Sorry for the long winded answer, but hopefully it explains it from the beginning enough that anyone else looking to find an answer can get the whole picture if they've not come as far as you have in this script.

Answer (score 0):

From `MouseEvent`, we have `clientX` and `movememntX`. Taken together, we can deduce our last location. We can then take the transform of our current location and subtract it from the transform of our last location:

```js
element.onpointermove = e => {
    const { clientX, clientY, movementX, movementY } = e;
    const DOM_pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
    DOM_pt.x = clientX;
    DOM_pt.y = clientY;
    const { x, y } = DOM_pt.matrixTransform(svgs[i].getScreenCTM().inverse());
    DOM_pt.x += movementX;
    DOM_pt.y += movementY;
    const { x: last_x, y: last_y } = DOM_pt.matrixTransform(svgs[i].getScreenCTM().inverse());
    const dx = last_x - x;
    const dy = last_y - y;
    // TODO: use dx & dy
}
```